# How to extract iframe's redirect url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect, iframe

I searched alot but didn't find(or I didn't understand those solutions) what im looking for. I want to extract redirect url from an iframe. For example, I embedded xyz.com in an iframe and now when iframe gets loaded on client browser, it gets redirected to example.com/.

I want to extract redirected url, i.e example.com/

Thanks

Comment: What domain is your code running in?  You'll run into a ton of issues unless your code is also running in xyz.com.

Comment: That's on my domain, but i can still load xyz.com in iframe.

Comment: I don't believe there's a way to do what you're trying to do.  At least with iframes anyway..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your iframe is on the same domain, you can select the iframe, select the contents of iframe, select what has your redirect url, use window.location to redirect:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('iframeId');
var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
var redirect = innerDoc.getElementById('redirectURL').innerHTML;
window.location = redirect;
```

if it's not, you won't be able to get the contents due to cross site scripting

Comment: Thanks! sadly iframe is on my owned domain and xyz.com is different domain.

Comment: Vote if that helped?